# 'Element type is invalid: expected a string' when passing params through component in Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I was looking for an info on how to pass params into a component in Route, and came across the following article:
*https://dev.to/paramharrison/how-to-pass-props-to-the-route-component-in-react-router-4o49*

The article provides 2 solutions:

1. passing params through render i.e.

```
      <Route exact path="/props-through-render" render={(props) => <PropsPage {...props} title={`Props through render`} />} />
```

2. passing params through component i.e.

```
      <Route exact path="/props-through-component" component={() => <PropsPage title={`Props through component`} />} />
```

where PropsPage is a function, which takes title param e.g.

```
const PropsPage = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <h3>{title}</h3>
  );
};
```

I am new to React (and ES6 too), so having hard time understanding this notation, where function body becomes just a tag being represented by another function i.e.  `() => <PropsPage .../>`. So on this topic, could somebody kindly explain or point me to some online resource explaining that notation?

Now to the main issue.
I decided to refactor the above Route invocations using more understandable for me way, and ended up with following:

```
1)         <Route
              exact
              path="/props-through-render"
              render={(props) => (PropsPage ({...props, title: 'Props through render'}))}
            />

2)          <Route
              exact
              path="/props-through-component"
              component={PropsPage ({title: 'Props through component'})
              }   
            />
```

So the refactored 'props-through-render' works, but the refactored 'props-through-component' throws the following error:
**Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

Looks like something wrong with the syntax, but I can't figure out what.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this ES6 notation `() => <PropsPage .../>` is the equivalent with the following:

```
function () {
    return <PropsPage .../>;
}
```

Since it has only one line in the return statement, there's no need to use return keyword in the new notation (you still can use it if you want).

In the first solution you mentioned, whenever the route matches with the given path, it renders whatever is returned from the inner function.

For the second solution, the function given as the component value must return a class-component. I believe that's why you're getting that error.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I updated my code, so the function returns a class component as below, but the error still persists.

`
class component:

class PropsPageClass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: props.title
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (<div><h1>
            {this.state.title}
        </h1></div>);
    }
}
export default PropsPageClass;
`
Updated function:
`
const PropsPage = ({ title }) => {
      return (
      <PropsPageClass title={title}/>
    );
};`

Comment: are you using first or second approach?

Comment: I am using the second approach i.e. the function returns a class component.
Please see the code for the class component and the updated function returning that class component in my last comment.